# Jenkins Dynamic stage creation in declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I need to have a dynamic stages creation. Depending on the list size, it will have X amount of stages. Each of them will have stages before for allocation and preparation. As they have to run parallel, those stages have to be executed on each test bot.

The issue I have is everything has to be in a Script block due to the dynamic stage creation, but I cannot use most of the stuff like agent, stage block and such in it.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'agent' found among steps [VersionNumber, archive, bat, build, catchError, checkout, compareVersions, container, containerLog, deleteDir, dir, dockerFingerprintFrom, dockerFingerprintRun, dockerNode, echo, emailext, emailextrecipients, envVarsForTool, error, fileExists, findBuildScans, findFiles, gerritCheck, gerritComment, gerritReview, getContext, git, input, isUnix, jiraAddComment...
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are in Scripted Syntax you can't use declarative syntax like `agent`. Instead of using `agent` use `node`

```
node('label') {  
    stage('Build') { 
        //Something 
    }
```

Comment: is the scripted block treated like it suddenly is a scripted pipeline?
Currently the whole pipeline is declarative which causes me the issues in the scripted block

Comment: @workingJeff You can use Declarative syntax outside of the Script block. But whatever is in the Script block should follow scripted Pipeline syntax.